Very slow keyboard in Xubuntu graphical user interface after upgrade from 20.04 to 24.04.1
When X starts in the log in screen, I can type my password normally. Once I click on the Log In button, the keyboard barely responds. This problem occurs in any window that requires keyboard input (e.g. Firefox, Mousepad, Xfce terminal, X terminal, etc.).
When I first performed the upgrade, I didn't notice this right away in Firefox, because I use a lot of bookmarks. But then I noticed I couldn't type anything in any of the input fields. I started trying other windows like the terminals and Mousepad and the problem appeared in all the applications.
I tried tweaking the keyboard in the settings menu, but it only allows key press Repeat delays and Repeat speed. I tried setting these to 220 for Repeat delay and 1 for Repeat speed. This helps slightly, but this is obviously not close to an actual fix. (I can maybe type about 4 words a minute.)
Sometimes Ctrl+Alt+Fx (where x can be 1 through 6) will allow me to get into a plain text terminal. The keyboard works normally there. It also works normally if I boot directly into text terminal. I suspect there might be a way to set the Graphical User Interface keyboard settings to a "factory default" setting from there a text terminal, but I don't know how to do this yet.
I am experiencing this problem on a Lenovo ThinkPad T61 with 4GB memory.

Note: I have tried the new kernel that was installed with 24.04.1 (6.8.0-45-generic) as well as the previous kernel from before the upgrade (5.15.0-generic). No noticeable difference.

Is the compositor enabled? Make sure you are using the compositor. I think it's in your window manager options. From my experience, Xfce seems to perform much worse in low graphics mode when the compositor is disabled because everything is handled by the cpu.

The solution turned out to be:
Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard > then Uncheck Slow keys and Bounce keys.
I can now type normally.
Note that this is different than Keyboard in the Settings menu.
